# run script asynchronously / in a different process

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, php, async

I have a simple php script

```php
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
sleep(1);
echo $i;
}
```

Which I run from the command line

```
php myfile.php &
```

I would expect I can do other things in the command line, even before the scripts ends.
I do get a prompt, but when I press the enter I get
`[1]+  Stopped                 php myfile.php`

Answer (score 2):

This is expected if your terminal has the `tostop` option enabled. When that is set, any background process that tries to output to the terminal receives the [`SIGTTOU`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTOU) signal, and that signal's default handler stops the process. (This is done so that output from background processes doesn't mess up your terminal.)

You can disable this feature by running `stty -tostop`, in the same terminal.

#### Your current situation:

```
$ stty tostop
$ php ./t.php &
[1] 6484
$ 
[1]+  Stopped                 php ./t.php
$ # no messing up of the terminal, process stopped
$ fg
php ./t.php
0^C
$
```

#### Disable that feature:

```
$ stty -tostop
$ php ./t.php &
[1] 6481
$ # 01an2d 3now 45 6it m7esses 8up 9my term!
```

Comment: did the stty -tostop (with and without sudo) still not workin, same message

Comment: this needs to be in the _same_ terminal you run php from, just as in the examples I posted.

Comment: It is in the same terminal. It seems like an issue of Ubuntu. If I do the & from inside a php file it works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "do the & from inside the php file"?

Comment: inside the php I do [backtik]php t.php>log &[backtik]  This, in php, runs the command inside the backtiks at the shell level (Did I say it right?). If I do that, the script runs async i.e. I can use the command line and the t.php runs in the background and outputs into **log**

Comment: Redirecting to a log file changes everything. It should prevent this problem from the command line too.

Comment: Some credit :-) I tried the same thing from command line, with the redirection to log, still, not working. It will show me the process is waiting in the background, but will run only when I do the `fg`

Comment: Does you script wait for user _input_?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better solution, but for me, on Ubuntu, it works if you run it in the foreground and suspend it with **Ctrl-Z**, and then background it with `bg`:

```
$ php myfile.php 
^Z
[4]+  Stopped                 php myfile.php
$ bg
[4]+ php myfile.php &
$ 2#3 it4 mess5es up 6my 7term8in9al too!
[4]   Done                    php myfile.php
```

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 --